# Find query with conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of documents where each document has the following properties: `userId`, `permissions`.

How can I use the `findOne` query to return a document that has `userId = 41` AND `permissions = admin` OR `permissions = op-admin` ?

I've tried the following query but it doesn't returns any results...

```
User.findOne(
  {
    'userId': 42
  },
  {
    $and: [
      {
        $or: {'permissions': 'admin'}
      },
      {
        $or: {'permissions': 'op-admin'}
      }
    ]
  }, function(err, doc) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(doc);
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Is there something I'm not doing correctly?

Comment: `.find({ "userId": 42, "permissions": { "$in": ['admin','op-admin'] } })`. The `$in` is basically shorthand for `$or` but applied to the same key. You also almost never actually need to use the terse `$and`. Thanks robert

Comment: @NeilLunn also needs the `userId` ;D

Comment: @NeilLunn I tried your code and also added `userId` to the query and it works perfectly. You should post this comment as an answer

Comment: I know it works.What you need to understand is "why it works, and why what you tried did not". Take a look at the documentation for the operators and see that `$or` in fact requires a "list", which you did not give, and therefore got a syntax error. Then look at the actual documentation for both `$in` and `$and` and see why you use `$in` here, and also what is actually said about the usage of `$and`. More useful time spent than marking an answer correct for a syntax correction.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
User.find({
          $and: [  {'userId': 42 } ,
              { $or: [ {'permissions': 'admin'}, {'permissions': 'op-admin'} ] }
          ]})
```